# javascript map function returning

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to assign idNumber of all participants to idNumbers. Can you please check my code?

```js
const participants = [
  { name: 'Abu', idNumber: 'S7282395H', gender: 'male' },
  { name: 'Mary', idNumber: 'T4689018Z', gender: 'female' },
  { name: 'Suzi', idNumber: 'G5512873T', gender: 'female' },
  { name: 'T Chakra', idNumber: 'T8198514B', gender: 'male' }
];
// pass a function to map
const getIds= participants.map((name) => `${participants.name} ${participants.idNumber}`);
console.log(getIds);
```

Comment: Hi! What help do you need specifically? Is this code not doing what you want? What does it output, and what do you need it to output instead?

Comment: `const getIds = participants.map((p) => \`${p.name} ${p.idNumber}\`);`

Comment: You just edited your question to something completely and not remotely related. Why is that? We can't really help you if you completely flip the script out of nowhere. This should have been made into a new question probably, since now all the answers look like they don't belong at all...

Comment: I've rolled back your edit, which as Lushmoney said should have been entered as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be referencing `name` and not `participants` inside the `map`:

```js
const participants = [
  { name: 'Abu', idNumber: 'S7282395H', gender: 'male' },
  { name: 'Mary', idNumber: 'T4689018Z', gender: 'female' },
  { name: 'Suzi', idNumber: 'G5512873T', gender: 'female' },
  { name: 'T Chakra', idNumber: 'T8198514B', gender: 'male' }
];
// pass a function to map
const getIds= participants.map((name) => `${name.name} ${name.idNumber}`);
console.log(getIds);
```

Comment: Surely this qualifies as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an array of `idNumber` then you can use `map` like this

```js
const participants = [
{ name: 'Abu', idNumber: 'S7282395H', gender: 'male' },
{ name: 'Mary', idNumber: 'T4689018Z', gender: 'female' },
{ name: 'Suzi', idNumber: 'G5512873T', gender: 'female' },
{ name: 'T Chakra', idNumber: 'T8198514B', gender: 'male' }];

const getIds = participants.map(participant =>  participant.idNumber);

console.log(getIds);
```

If you want an array of strings containing the name and the idNumber you can use string interpolation for that.

```js
const participants = [
{ name: 'Abu', idNumber: 'S7282395H', gender: 'male' },
{ name: 'Mary', idNumber: 'T4689018Z', gender: 'female' },
{ name: 'Suzi', idNumber: 'G5512873T', gender: 'female' },
{ name: 'T Chakra', idNumber: 'T8198514B', gender: 'male' }];

const getIds = participants.map(participant =>  `${participant.name} ${participant.idNumber}`);

console.log(getIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this piece of code

```js
const getIds= participants.map((name) => `${participants.name} ${participants.idNumber}`);
```

you need to reference the `name` argument, not participants. That needs to be

```js
const getIds= participants.map((name) => `${name.name} ${name.idNumber}`);
```

I recommend changing the `name` parameter to something more distinct, since `name.name` is not really *clean*, per se...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but it sounds like you want to get an array of all participant `idNumber` values. In that case, perhaps something like this?

```
const idNumbers = participants.map((participant) => participant.idNumber));
```

In your code inside the `map` callback, you're currently trying to access `name` and `idNumber` from `participants`, which will return `undefined` since `participants` is an array and doesn't have those props. What you want to do is access these props in each individual `participant` from the callback argument.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map